# Script to import Kucoin Prices needs updating

Tags: api

Using google sheets in the past (Haven't used it since the beginning of Covid), I have used this script to import crypto prices from the Kucoin exchange into specific cells:

```
function Get_KuCoinPrice(market)
{
// example HST-BTC
var url = "https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick?symbol="+market;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var text = response.getContentText();
var myjson = JSON.parse(text);
var price = myjson.data.lastDealPrice;
return price;
}
```

To Call the code into my sheet, I use the following"

```
=Get_KuCoinPrice("BTCUSD")
```

Now it no longer works.. And I am unable to figure out what changes to the script is needed with the new API code..

The new api url for symbol info is:

```
https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol=
```

So, when I execute the URL with the symbol:

```
https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol=BTC-USDT
```

The resulting page is:

```
{
"code": "200000",
"data": {
"time": 1646712219273,
"sequence": "1626697837569",
"price": "38710.7",
"size": "0.00049864",
"bestBid": "38710.6",
"bestBidSize": "0.00471936",
"bestAsk": "38710.7",
"bestAskSize": "1.30314071"
}
}
```

So, what I really need to know is how do I reconfigure the script to pull the "price" into my google sheet with the new api?

Answer (score 0):

The site returns `The api version you are using has been disabled. Please use the latest url of api.`

https://docs.kucoin.com/#upcoming-changes

Use the new API

Comment: Yes, I understand, but do not know what needs to be changed in the script to make it work.

Comment: This is not the right place to get help, try to find a forum about kucoin or the company itself.

Comment: https://algotrading101.com/learn/kucoin-api-guide/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=kucoin-api-guide